# Website for Sat details

Tags: satellites

I used to use the [Amsat](http://www.amsat.org/amsat-new/satellites/status.php) website for finding out the status of Sats and other info, like operating frequency etc. It was proving useful, and I like the pass predictor also. Seems nowadays though there's error messages with the database, I get:

> *** Database Error - sql - InitDB line 14

on a lot of pages, particularly with the status page of interest.

Are there any good sites out there? I'm stuck for a current list of functional sats that I should track and their associated operating frequency detail, modes, beacons etc.

Cheers, 73

Comment: Normally, when encountering errors such as these, it would be better to report them to the owner of the web site in question. Particularly as they are unlikely to persue a fairly random web site on the off chance that someone might mention there that they had some problem with their service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported the problem with Amsat.org and received a reply indicating the site is under re-construction but usable in part.  More than a year ago they were hacked and had to move to a new platform.  The old SQL database is not operational and so old links and some of the pages linked to from up-to-date pages may get the "sql - InitDB line 14" error.

Old links are likely to have problems, but if you start at [www.amsat.org](http://www.amsat.org) some of the functionality is available.  The pass prediction page linked from there actually looks like it mostly works despite showing the database error at the bottom.  Their "Current Status" submenu links off to another site, [oscar.dcarr.org](http://oscar.dcarr.org).

Answer (score 2):

AMSAT's [website](http://www.amsat.org/amsat-new/satellites/status.php) appears broken.  I wonder if they even know?  I don't what functionality it had, but N2YO's site [here](http://www.n2yo.com/satellites/?c=18) has all the satellites listed and tracking information and is the one I use.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Most useful. Be good when amsat are fully back online glad they know the issues.